# ¿Por qué se usa la palabra "le" en lugar de "les" en esta oración?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, pronombres

Leí esta oración en un libro.

"¿Qué te parecería si le dijéramos a los que estén interesados que se reúnan con nosotros en el pueblo para que podamos discutirlo?"

Lo que quiero entender es por qué "le" se usa aquí, cuando se refiere "a los que estén interesados".

Si "los que estén interesados" es plural ¿por qué no es "les"?

Comment: la pregunta debería ser "por qué", y no "para qué" (a manera de ejemplo, si el inglés te es el idioma familiar:  lo que quieres preguntar es "why" (por qué), sin embargo, el "para qué" sería equivalente a "what for" — "what is the word "le"used for, instead of .... ")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La oración:

- ¿Qué te parecería si le dijéramos a los que estén interesados que se reúnan con nosotros en el pueblo para que podamos discutirlo?

es **incorrecta por falta de concordancia** entre los dos complementos indirectos, el pronominal "le" (singular) y el nominal "a **los que** estén interesados" (plural). El complemento indirecto átono se usa para reforzar el complemento indirecto nominal y debería ser plural:

- ¿Qué te parecería si **les** dijéramos a los que estén interesados que se reúnan con nosotros en el pueblo para que podamos discutirlo?

[Fuente](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/les-dijo-a-ellos-no-le-dijo-a-ellos-concordancia/):

El pronombre *le* se emplea en plural (*les*) cuando el complemento al que se refiere también es plural: «El funcionario **les** dijo **a los asistentes** que se fueran» y **no** «El funcionario **le** dijo **a los asistentes** que se fueran».

Es común encontrar en la prensa casos en los que se descuida esa concordancia, como los siguientes: «El ente del fútbol sudamericano le ofreció a los clubes argentinos una dosis de la vacuna Sinovac», «Le indicó a los acusados que cumplirían al menos dos tercios de sus condenas bajo custodia» o «La Casa Blanca también hizo hincapié en decirle a los periodistas que Biden estaba concentrado en otras áreas de su agenda, incluyendo la covid».

Como explica la Gramática, en este tipo de estructuras, **los pronombres átonos concuerdan con el grupo nominal al que hacen referencia**. Es decir, lo adecuado es escribir *me, te, le* cuando es singular («me dijo a mí», «te dijo a ti», «le dijo a él»), y *nos, os, les* cuando es plural («nos dijo a nosotros», «os dijo a vosotros», «les dijo a ellos»).

Utilizar *le* cuando su referente es plural produce una clara discordancia que, aunque bastante extendida, se desaconseja en el registro formal y, como también indica *El buen uso del español*, de la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española, da lugar a oraciones incorrectas.

En consecuencia, en los ejemplos citados lo apropiado habría sido escribir: «El ente del fútbol sudamericano **les** ofreció **a los clubes argentinos** una dosis de la vacuna Sinovac», «**Les** indicó **a los acusados** que cumplirían al menos dos tercios de sus condenas bajo custodia» o «La Casa Blanca también hizo hincapié en decir**les a los periodistas** que Biden estaba concentrado en otras áreas de su agenda, incluyendo la covid».

Comment: ¿Así que esto es una forma de jerga? Porque se lo pregunté yo a una amiga, la que es una hablante natal, y me dijo que esto es correcto decir, pero que no pudo explicarme el porqué.

Comment: No es jerga: es un error muy extendido entre los hablantes.